# Group pandas dataframe and flag corresponding rows where all values from a list exist in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
Group1 Group2 Label
G1     A1    AA
G1     A1    BB
G1     A1    CC
G1     A2    AA
G1     A2    CC
G2     A1    BB
G2     A1    DD
G2     A2    AA
G2     A2    CC
G2     A2    DD
G2     A2    BB

l1 = ['AA','BB','CC','DD']
```

I want to group the dataframe based on the `Group1` and `Group2` columns and check if the 'Label' column is equal(ordering may be different) to a list of values (`l1`), and flag those group.

Expected output:
The group `Group1=G2`, `Group2=A2` has all values from `l1` in the `Label` column. Therefore the rows corresponding to the group are flagged.

```
Group1 Group2 Label  Flag
G1     A1    AA     0
G1     A1    BB     0
G1     A1    CC     0
G1     A2    AA     0
G1     A2    CC     0
G2     A1    BB     0
G2     A1    DD     0
G2     A2    AA     1
G2     A2    CC     1
G2     A2    DD     1
G2     A2    BB     1
```

I haven't been able to make much progress:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
                'Group1': [ 'G1','G1', 'G1','G1','G1',
                            'G2','G2', 'G2','G2','G2','G2'],
                'Group2': ['A1','A1','A1','A2','A2',
                            'A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A2'],
                'Label': ['AA','BB','CC','AA','CC','BB',
                            'DD','AA','CC','DD','BB']})
df.groupby(['Group1','Group2'])
```

A link to a solution or a function/method I can use to achieve this is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and `set` operations:

```
l1 = ['AA','BB','CC','DD']
S = set(l1)

df['Flag'] = (df
 .groupby(['Group1','Group2'])
 ['Label'].transform(lambda x: set(x)==S)
 .astype(int)
 )
```

Output:

```
   Group1 Group2 Label  Flag
0      G1     A1    AA     0
1      G1     A1    BB     0
2      G1     A1    CC     0
3      G1     A2    AA     0
4      G1     A2    CC     0
5      G2     A1    BB     0
6      G2     A1    DD     0
7      G2     A2    AA     1
8      G2     A2    BB     1
9      G2     A2    CC     1
10     G2     A2    DD     1
```

Comment: What if the order within the set is different from column order?

Comment: Sets are unordered. Try to shuffle `l1`, Todd won't change the result.

Comment: (*this). Also note that you can use `lambda x: set(x)>=S` of you want to allow other items than just those of `l1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `.agg(set)` and `df.join()`

```
cols = ['Group1','Group2']
df.join(df.groupby(cols)['Label'].agg(set).eq(set(l1)).rename('Flag').astype(int),on = cols)
```

or

```
df['Label'].str.get_dummies().reindex(l,axis=1).groupby([df['Group1'],df['Group2']]).transform('any').all(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   Group1 Group2 Label  Flag
0      G1     A1    AA     0
1      G1     A1    BB     0
2      G1     A1    CC     0
3      G1     A2    AA     0
4      G1     A2    CC     0
5      G2     A1    BB     0
6      G2     A1    DD     0
7      G2     A2    AA     1
8      G2     A2    CC     1
9      G2     A2    DD     1
10     G2     A2    BB     1
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Fast solution

```
df['flag'] = df['Label'].mask(~df['Label'].isin(l1))
df['flag'] = df.groupby(['Group1', 'Group2'])['flag'].transform('nunique').eq(len(l1))
```

---

```
   Group1 Group2 Label   flag
0      G1     A1    AA  False
1      G1     A1    BB  False
2      G1     A1    CC  False
3      G1     A2    AA  False
4      G1     A2    CC  False
5      G2     A1    BB  False
6      G2     A1    DD  False
7      G2     A2    AA   True
8      G2     A2    CC   True
9      G2     A2    DD   True
10     G2     A2    BB   True
```